# Dynamically loading plugin jars using ServiceLoader

Tags: java, jar, classpath, serviceloader

I'm trying to create a plugin system for my application, and I want to start with something simple. Every plugin should be packed in a .jar file and implement the `SimplePlugin` interface:

```
package plugintest;

public interface SimplePlugin {
    public String getName();
}
```

Now I've created an implementation of `SimplePlugin`, packed in a .jar and put it in the plugin/ subdirectory of the main application:

```
package plugintest;

public class PluginTest implements SimplePlugin {
    public String getName() {
        return "I'm the plugin!";
    }
}
```

In the main application, I want to get an instance of `PluginTest`. I've tried two alternatives, both using `java.util.ServiceLoader`.

**1. Dynamically extending the classpath**

This uses the known hack to use reflection on the system class loader to avoid encapsulation, in order to add `URL`s the the classpath.

```
package plugintest.system;

import plugintest.SimplePlugin;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class ManagePlugins {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File loc = new File("plugins");
        extendClasspath(loc);

        ServiceLoader<SimplePlugin> sl = ServiceLoader.load(SimplePlugin.class);
        Iterator<SimplePlugin> apit = sl.iterator();
        while (apit.hasNext())
            System.out.println(apit.next().getName());
    }

    private static void extendClasspath(File dir) throws IOException {
        URLClassLoader sysLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        URL urls[] = sysLoader.getURLs(), udir = dir.toURI().toURL();
        String udirs = udir.toString();
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++)
            if (urls[i].toString().equalsIgnoreCase(udirs)) return;
        Class<URLClassLoader> sysClass = URLClassLoader.class;
        try {
            Method method = sysClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(sysLoader, new Object[] {udir});
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The plugins/ directory is added as expected (as one can check calling `sysLoader.getURLs()`), but then the iterator given by the `ServiceLoader` object is empty.

**2. Using URLClassLoader**

This uses another definition of `ServiceLoader.load` with a second argument of the class `ClassLoader`.

```
package plugintest.system;

import plugintest.SimplePlugin;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class ManagePlugins {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File loc = new File("plugins");

        File[] flist = loc.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File file) {return file.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar");}
        });
        URL[] urls = new URL[flist.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < flist.length; i++)
            urls[i] = flist[i].toURI().toURL();
        URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

        ServiceLoader<SimplePlugin> sl = ServiceLoader.load(SimplePlugin.class, ucl);
        Iterator<SimplePlugin> apit = sl.iterator();
        while (apit.hasNext())
            System.out.println(apit.next().getName());
    }
}
```

Once again, the iterator has never a "next" element.

There's surely something I'm missing since it's the first time I'm "playing" with class paths and loading.

Comment: why not use a simple library with reflection support? such as apache common configuration with beans support: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_beans.html#Declaring_and_Creating_Beans

Comment: @omerschleifer Because, as I said, it's the first time I'm playing with these sort of things and I want to learn how they work. Secondly, your advice is welcome but libraries have the common problem that they can do way more than what you want to do, so things are often more complicated than necessary. I don't know if it's the case, but I want to resolve to an external library only if it's my last chance.

Comment: If this is for educational purposes, have fun. but as for complexity, reflection is much easier to perform and master using a simple library like the one I've sent you rather than by inventing the wheel yourself. Reflection is, after all, a well explored area. good luck

Comment: I wanted to use this prinzip to load plugin-jar from anywhere on the harddrive. But for some reason I get an `ClassNotFoudException` on the iterator.next. Have you any Idea how to use this principal with external jars?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem was very simple. And stupid. In the plugin .jar files the `/services/plugintest.SimplePlugin` file was missing inside the `META-INF` directory, so the `ServiceLoader` couldn't identify the jars as services and load the class.

That's pretty much all, the second (and cleaner) way works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

Starting from Java 9 the service providing scanning will be much easier and efficient. No more need for `META-INF/services`.

In the interface module declaration declare:

```
uses com.foo.spi.Service;
```

And in the provider's module:

```
provides com.foo.spi.Service with com.bar.ServiceImplementation
```

Comment: So this solves the issue of finding plugins in program-specified paths - how?

Comment: `ServiceLoader` isn't really well geared for this, the jar must already be in the classpath or modulepath.

Comment: You could add jars dynamically though. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-to-load-jar-files-dynamically-at-runtime/59743937#59743937

Comment: Also, the `ServiceLoader` constructor has overloads that accept `ClassLoader` or `ModuleLayer` so you can still do some dynamics with it.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for your application concept has been already described in Oracle Documentation (including dynamically loading JARs)

**Creating Extensible Applications With the Java Platform**
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/extensible-137159.html

on the bottom of the article you will find links to

- source code of the example
- Javadoc  ServiceLoader API

In my opinion it is better to slightly modify Oracle's example than reinventing the wheel as Omer Schleifer said.