# How to customize where ServiceLoader looks for Plugin Jars

Tags: java, serviceloader

I have a multimodule project with two projects: **Core** and **A**. The idea is to launch/ run A whenever Core is launched.

How can I customize the ServiceLoader to look up and call the modules in the **Plugins** folder from core?

```
plugin-Project
    + Core
        + src\main\java
            Core.java

    + A
        + src\main\java
            A.java

    + Plugins
```

**Core**

```
public class Core extends Application {

    private ServiceLoader<View> views;
    private BorderPane mainBorderPane;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        loadViews();
    }

    private void loadViews() {
        views = ServiceLoader.load(View.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Ui Application");

        mainBorderPane = new BorderPane();
        mainBorderPane.setTop(createMenuBar());

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 800, 605);
        scene.setRoot(mainBorderPane);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private MenuBar createMenuBar() {
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu viewMenu = new Menu("Views");
        menuBar.getMenus().add(viewMenu);

        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        views.forEach(v -> {
            RadioMenuItem item = new RadioMenuItem(v.getName());
            item.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
            item.setOnAction(event -> {
                Label label = new Label(v.getName());
                mainBorderPane.setLeft(label);
                mainBorderPane.setCenter(v.getView());
            });
            viewMenu.getItems().add(item);
        });
        return menuBar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**View.java**

```
public interface View {

    String getName();

    Node getView();
}
```

---

**Scenario**

The application I'm working on is an multi-module stand-alone desktop application. For example, Core would hold a pane on the left **(left-pane)**. left-pane will accept `nodes` from any module that implements an interface called `LeftPane`. **A** implements the `LeftPane` interface. Whenever Core is launched, it should scan through a folder, plugins in this case and automatically start all the bundles there, including A, which would go on to populate the left pane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way of course would be to have the plugins already on the classpath. Then you can simply access the interfaces through the `ServiceLoader`.

Or you provide a mechanism, that will detect your plugin jar files at a specific location and adds them to the class path. This is the tricky part. One way to do this is by using a custom `ClassLoader` for your application that allows adding jar files to the classpath.

I have chosen a different approach, that access the non public API of the `ClassLoader` that is in use for my application:

```
private void addFile(File f) throws IOException // URL to your plugin jar file
{
    addURL(f.toURI().toURL());
}

private void addURL(URL u) throws IOException
{
    URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;

    try {
        Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", parameters);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(sysloader, new Object[] {u});
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When the plugin jar file is on the classpath you can access an exposed interface through the `ServiceLoader`. Let me illustrate this with an example. The interface that is exposed can look like this:

```
/**
 * Interface to allow plugins to contribute resource reference properties.
 */
public interface IResourcePropertyLoader {
    /**
     * Retrieve the base name for the additional text resource.
     * @return
     */
    String getResourcePropertyBaseName();
}
```

The interface (which can also be a base class) is part of your core application. The plugin has a class that implements this interface.

Next you do the lookup for all implementations of that interface:

```
ServiceLoader<ITextPropertyLoader> loader = ServiceLoader.load(ITextPropertyLoader.class, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

The `ServiceLoader` implements `Iterable`, and therefore you can loop over all the implementations:

```
for (ITextPropertyLoader textProperty : loader) {
    final String textPropertyBaseName = textProperty.getTextPropertyBaseName();
    System.out.println("Found text property with name: " + textPropertyBaseName);
}
```

Also take a look at [Oracles documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) on this as well as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102010/dynamically-loading-plugin-jars-using-serviceloader)

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev added a bit more details on the use of `ServiceLoader`.