# ServiceLoader, URLClassLoader & Spring: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, serviceloader

I'm trying to load an external module.jar, which implements an Interface from my main spring application.

Therefore I implemented [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16102010/dynamically-loading-plugin-jars-using-serviceloader?rq=1)

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    File loc = new File("plugins");

    File[] flist = loc.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {return file.getPath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar");}
    });

    URL[] urls = new URL[flist.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < flist.length; i++) {
        try {
            urls[i] = flist[i].toURI().toURL();
            System.out.println(flist[i].toURI().toURL().toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    ServiceLoader<DeviceInterface> sl = ServiceLoader.load(DeviceInterface.class, ucl);
    Iterator<DeviceInterface> apit = sl.iterator();
    while (apit.hasNext())
        System.out.println(apit.next().getName());
}
```

Unfortunatly this throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/maxrakete/james/device/domain/DeviceInterface
```

Am I supposed to declare my main application as a dependency in my module? Currently my module only has its own dependencies.

The rescources I found online were not really clear about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could be springboot packaging problem. Try to add repackage to your maven build

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>exec</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: To my main application l assume?

Comment: Unfortunatly that did not solve my problem. I still get the same error