# Dynamic Loading of Java 9+ Modules

Tags: java, javafx, java-module

I have been trying to write a program, in using Java 11.0.2, which loads plugins (as jars) from a designated directory. In doing so, I followed the code suggested by ZhekaKozov, in his answer to [How do I dynamically load modules from a directory in Java 9+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62742150/how-do-i-dynamically-load-modules-from-a-directory-in-java-9)

In my case, I am using Java 9+ modules, with a module for the application and another for the plugin it loads. A third module provides some generic code that the other two can access. I suspect it is modularity that is causing the problem I have. In the simple example I'll provide, I run the application, which opens as a window with a panel containing a button. When I click the button, the plugin should load and run as a service, adding a second button to the panel. When that button is clicked a Window opens to show that it is working.

The problem is that when I run the application from a jar and click the first button, I get the following exception:

```
com.example.dynamic.feature    
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.graphics not found, required by com.example.dynamic.feature
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.findFail(Resolver.java:877)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:191)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolve(Resolver.java:140)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:411)
        at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolve(Configuration.java:245)
        at com.recite.dynamic.client.Client.loadPlugins(Client.java:94)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I run it with:

java -jar com.example.dynamic.client.jar

The code for the application (Client) is:

```
package com.example.dynamic.client;

<numerous imports> ...

public class Client extends Application
{
    private Stage stage;
    private HBox basePane;

    @FXML
    private Button btnLoadPlugins;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        this.stage = stage;

        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com.example.dynamic.toolbar/fxml/client.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);

            basePane = loader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(basePane);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

            stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> close());
            btnLoadPlugins.setOnAction(actionEvent -> Platform.runLater(this::loadPlugins));

            stage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void close()
    {
        stage.hide();

        Platform.exit();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private void loadPlugins()
    {
        Path pluginsDir = Paths.get("E:\\DynamicModules\\MinimalExample\\DynamicMinimalExample\\plugins");

        ModuleFinder pluginsFinder = ModuleFinder.of(pluginsDir);

        List<String> plugins = pluginsFinder
                .findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(ModuleReference::descriptor)
                .map(ModuleDescriptor::name)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        plugins.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));

        Configuration pluginsConfiguration = ModuleLayer
                .boot()
                .configuration()
                .resolve(pluginsFinder, ModuleFinder.of(), plugins);

        System.out.println("create module layer");

        ModuleLayer layer = ModuleLayer
                .boot()
                .defineModulesWithOneLoader(pluginsConfiguration, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

        System.out.println("loading services");

        List<IFeatureAccessor> services = ServiceLoader
                .load(layer, IFeatureAccessor.class)
                .stream()
                .map(ServiceLoader.Provider::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //Stop the same service from installing twice. I'm sure there's a far better solution
        services.forEach(iFeatureAccessor -> {
            Set<String> ids = new HashSet<>();

            basePane.getChildren().forEach(button -> {
                if (button.getId() != null)
                {
                    ids.add(button.getId());
                }
            });

            if (!ids.contains(iFeatureAccessor.getButton().getId()))
            {
                basePane.getChildren().add(iFeatureAccessor.getButton());
            }
        });
    }
}

module com.example.dynamic.feature {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires com.example.dynamic.generic;

    exports com.example.dynamic.feature;
    provides com.example.dynamic.generic.IFeatureAccessor with com.example.dynamic.feature.FeatureController;
}
```

---

The client runs from a simple launcher class and works perfectly until I click to load the plugin.

The generic code is:

```
package com.example.dynamic.generic;

import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public interface IFeatureAccessor
{
    Button getButton();
    void toggle();
}

module com.example.dynamic.generic {
    exports com.example.dynamic.generic;
    requires javafx.controls;
}
```

---

The plugin (Feature) is:

```
package com.example.dynamic.feature;

import com.example.dynamic.generic.IFeatureAccessor;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class FeatureController implements IFeatureAccessor
{
    private final Button button;

    private VBox basePane;
    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;


    public FeatureController()
    {
        button = new Button("Feature");
        button.setId("com.example.dynamic.feature");

        button.setOnAction(event -> toggle());

        createScene();
    }

    private void createScene()
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com.example.dynamic.feature/fxml/feature.fxml"));
            loader.setController(this);

            basePane = loader.load();

            scene = new Scene(basePane);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Button getButton()
    {
        return button;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle()
    {
        if (stage == null)
        {
            stage = new Stage();

            stage.setTitle(((Stage) getButton().getScene().getWindow()).getTitle());
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            stage.initOwner(getButton().getScene().getWindow());

            stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> disable());
        }

        if(stage.isShowing())
        {
            disable();
        }
        else
        {
            enable();
        }
    }

    private void enable()
    {
        stage.show();
    }

    private void disable()
    {
        stage.hide();
    }
}

module com.example.dynamic.feature {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires com.example.dynamic.generic;

    exports com.example.dynamic.feature;
    provides com.example.dynamic.generic.IFeatureAccessor with com.example.dynamic.feature.FeatureController;
}
```

---

The jars are created, in IntelliJ Idea, from "Modules with dependencies". The following image shows the feature jar:

[image: Construction of the feature jar]

The client jar is constructed in a similar manner, with the addition of a manifest and main class defined.

Adding javafx.base to either or both jars makes no difference.

If I create a feature jar with no javafx or generic module in it, and run the application through IntelliJ Idea, it loads the jar and adds its button as expected. When I tried using the cut-down jar with the client run from a jar, it complained that it couldn't find javafx or the generic code, so i added them, as shown in the image. This resolved the problem but gave the exception mentioned at the top of this question.

We can see where the problem is, as the name of the feature prints out, as expected, but the line for printing "Create module layer" is never reached.

(Note: running the application through the IDE and loading the feature jar constructed as in the image results in a different exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module com.example.dynamic.feature contains package javafx.collections, module javafx.base exports package javafx.collections to com.example.dynamic.feature
```

).

I would be grateful if someone could let me know where I'm going wrong with this. It looks to me like the feature jar should be getting its javafx and generic code exported from the client.

Comment: The problem is likely due to how you're deploying the application. For one, the current implementation only supports one module per JAR file. Then there's the problem that `-jar` puts that JAR on the class-path (i.e. the unnamed module), so none of the JavaFX modules exist anymore regardless of the one-module-per-JAR-file problem. I'm actually surprised you don't get the "_Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application_" error with this setup.

Comment: In your case, you should probably make all your code modular and then run the application using those modules. First, don't create a fat/uber JAR file. Then you would execute `java --module-path <path> --module <module-name>/<main-class>` where `<path>` points to JavaFX and your main module(s). You may also want to look into `jlink` / `jpackage` for deployment. If you use those tools make sure to put JavaFX on the module-path and make sure to use the JavaFX JMOD files (not the regular JAR files). All this can be made even easier by downloading a Java distribution that includes JavaFX.

Comment: Thanks, Slaw, for your advice. I was puzzled by your statement that "For one, the current implementation only supports one module per JAR file." I wasn't sure if you were meaning any jar, the client jar, or the feature jar. Our applications have always worked OK with the javafx jars and dlls accessed from within the jar file (e.g. the client in the example application runs fine until told to load a plugin).

Comment: I've looked into your advice from your second comment, and it certainly does run from Java that way. Jlink worked, as did the packager (using Java 16 ) which generated a .exe installed, for the client, which loaded the plugin without problems. 

I found your advice useful. I was asked to investigate using java to load features as plugins when required, for a  program that could run from a jar where the user has no permissions to install executables. From what you say, it may well be that a jar-based client is not going to load plugins dynamically.

Comment: "_Our applications have always worked OK with the javafx jars and dlls accessed from within the jar file_" – but you probably weren't using modules anymore. A JAR file can only have one `module-info` descriptor. As for your problem regarding not being able to use `jlink` / `jpackage` for these particular users, there is another way. Basically, just do what you would have done pre-Java 9. Don't bother with module layers and such. Just create a e.g. `URLClassLoader` that loads the plugins. And have the plugin providers include a _provider-configuration file_ under `META-INF/services`.

Comment: Many thanks the URLClassloader solution does the job. I'd been under the impression that dynamic classloading was no longer possible in Java 11+, since they tightened-up access to the inner workings of the jre.